Seeking Exact Solution for Nonlinear PDE Involving Mixed Derivatives
I am trying to find an exact solution for the following nonlinear partial differential equation (PDE):
$$
-y u_x - u_y u_{xx} - u u_{xxy} + \frac{1}{2} u_{yy} = 0.
$$

I attempted the method of separation of variables and proposed a solution of the form:
$$
u(x, y) = (A e^{kx} + B e^{-kx}) \left( -\frac{y^2}{2} + C y + D \right).
$$

However, when verifying this solution by substituting it back into the PDE, I found that it does not satisfy the equation. I attempted using Mathematica and Python programs, but I was unable to obtain a correct solution.
EDIT: According to @Roland F answer: The equation can be integrated once. A product ansatz yields

$$
\begin{align}
 &\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left(\frac{u_y}{2}-u u_{x,x}\right)=y \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \\& 
 \frac{1}{2} u_y(x,y)-u(x,y) u_{x,x}(x,y)=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\int y \ u(x,y) \, dy  \\& \frac{1}{2} X(x) Y'(y)-X(x) Y(y)^2 \ X''(x)=X'(x) \ \int y\  Y(y) \, dy \\& \frac{1}{2}\ Y'(y)\frac{X(x)}{X'(x)}- Y(y)^2\ \frac{ X''(x)}{X'(x)}=\int y\ Y(y) \, dy 
\end{align}
$$
that is working if
$$
\frac{X''(x)}{X'(x)}=c_1,\quad \frac{X(x)}{X'(x)}=c_2 
$$

I am seeking help to complete the exact solution for this nonlinear PDE.
Thank you for your assistance!

No boundary conditions?

@Gonçalo Unfortunately no

What kind of solution are you looking for? $u(x,y)=A+By$ is a solution...

Thank you for your response. I am looking for a more general or specific form of the solution rather than just a linear solution like $ u(x, y) = A + By $. My goal is to find an exact solution that satisfies the given PDE:
$
-y u_x - u_y u_{xx} - u u_{xxy} + \frac{1}{2} u_{yy} = 0.
$
I am open to any insights, methods, or alternative forms of solutions that could potentially satisfy the PDE. Any detailed guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your assistance!

A pde is typically defined on a domain with some sort of conditions at the boundary. Is it safe to assume you’re thinking of its domain being all of  $R^2$?

@Aruralreader Yes please, thanks for your note

The equation can be integrated once. A product ansatz yields
$$\begin{align}
 &\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left(\frac{u_y}{2}-u u_{x,x}\right)=y \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \\& 
 \frac{1}{2} u_y(x,y)-u(x,y) u_{x,x}(x,y)=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\int y \ u(x,y) \, dy  \\& \frac{1}{2} X(x) Y'(y)-X(x) Y(y)^2 \ X''(x)=X'(x) \ \int y\  Y(y) \, dy \\& \frac{1}{2}\ Y'(y)\frac{X(x)}{X'(x)}- Y(y)^2\ \frac{ X''(x)}{X'(x)}=\int y\ Y(y) \, dy 
\end{align}$$
that is working if $$\frac{X''(x)}{X'(x)}=c_1,\quad \frac{X(x)}{X'(x)}=c_2 $$

So, what is the general solution for our PDE?

I forgot a tick  X' on the right. See the correction.

I think we still have a problem in your solution, you divided all terms by $X^{\prime}(x)$
$$\begin{aligned}&\frac12X(x)Y^{\prime}(y)-X(x)Y(y)^2X^{\prime\prime}(x)=X^{\prime}(x)\int yY(y)dy\&\frac12Y^{\prime}(y)\frac{X(x)}{X^{\prime}(x)}-Y(y)^2\frac{X^{\prime\prime}(x)}{X^{\prime}(x)}=\int yY(y)dy\end{aligned}$$
but you deleted $X(x)$ from the middle term, anything I missed?!
